# NodeJS monorepo - different NodeJS versions in different services?

Tags: node.js, monorepo

I'm working with a pretty big monorepo (~40 different services) and the team wants to upgrade the used NodeJS version in them incrementally (one-by-one upgrade from NodeJS 12 to 18).
Running `yarn` attempts to install dependencies from the root `package.json` and all the other `package.json`s of all the other services. This isn't good because some packages aren't supported with Node v18.

How can I change the NodeJS version for each service without it affecting the others? Is it even possible?

I tried to `cd` into the inner project, change to `18.12.0` using `nvm` and run `yarn clean && yarn`, but it tried to install packages from the root directory and up.